# Why does list columns appear twice after powershell export / import script execution?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, contenttype, site-column

i tried to write powershell scripts that export and import site columns and content-types (from [this](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/02/export-and-importcreate-site-content.html) article and [this](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/01/export-and-importcreate-site-columns-in.html)) from a SharePoint 2013 Site (RootWeb) from the site-collection A to the site-collection B.

When i execute these and export all the stuff and import it back again within sitecollection B, I have some duplicate fields within the new lists in sitecollection B. At the following pictures you can see a custom folder content type that inherits from "folder" that has two fields where users have to input a name:

[image: DispForm]

[image: EditForm]

[image: NewForm]

What is happening here? In list-settings and content-type settings i see no duplicated fields? I do not understand where is the problem, what did I do wrong?

Any help is highly appreciated!

EDIT:

The xml that i have exported for site columns (to import it later) does not contain standarad SharePoint columns like Name (FileLeafRef). But, the exported content type xml does use these standard columns from SharePoint, see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFsSz.png

Where is the mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you export only site columns that are custom columns and not site columns that are standard SharePoint installation. For example, the column « Name » is a built-in column in Sharepoint so you don't need to export this one cause it's already in sitecollection B.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand what you are talking about, but i dont know where is the error? Within the export site columns script or the import site columns script? Or the export content types script or the import content types script? There is no field like >> Name << How can i fix this annoying issue? Kind regards Joerg

Comment: I created a new content type in my environment with Folder as parent content type. When I export and import this one using the same PowerShell script that you mentionned in your question from site collection A to site collection B, I get the same problem. Using Sharepoint Manager, I compared the XML schema of the content type from site A and site B and I notice there is a difference. In the schema of the content type in site B, I have one more field. This field is named LinkFilenameNoMenu.

Comment: Hy Sylvain B, i deleted the FileLeafRef field for every content-type: <Field ID="{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}" Name="FileLeafRef" .../> and then it worked! Thank you very much for your help! Now I will modify my export content-types script and then everything will be fine. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you export only site columns that are custom columns and not site columns that are a standard part of the SharePoint installation.

For example, the fields named `LinkFilenameNoMenu` and`FileLeafRef` are built-in columns in Sharepoint so you don't need to export them; they will already be in the destination site collection.